# AWS Glue spark job - Snowflake connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the below error while running the AWS glue job using spark
Glue version 2.0 spark 2.4 python 3
Could you please let me know if anyone encountered similar issue using AWS glue and snowflake.

```
2021-04-27 13:59:23,858 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(91)): Exception in User Class
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1862)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendPlugin$class.launch(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.scala:10)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper$$anon$1.launch(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.scala:15)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.launch(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.scala:19)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.scala:5)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackendWrapper.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin$class.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:44)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:75)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:114)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:26)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /172.36.143.34:41447
```